# How to soften HDR shadow

Tags: lighting

So, I have an HDR file that is lighting my scene (https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=skies&h=yellow_field this one, to be specific), but it's casting rather sharp shadows onto my scene. This is undesirable in the context of my scene, but I'm not sure how to make it do anything else.

How do I soften the shadow cast by this HDR texture?

EDIT The answer given in the "duplicate question" section is not satisfactory to me. I wish to use this HDR file, adding additional light-bouncing objects would not work astonishingly well due to the nature of the scene, and blurring the HDRi as shown in that answer completely changes the appearance of the scene.

Comment: "not satisfactory" That is not a precise description, only you know what that means... please edit your question and add show what you have and in what way the proposed solutions do not work for you. The goal of this site is not to guess what you want, but to help you with concrete answers... but that requires clarity on the question.

Comment: Further clarified.

Comment: If you want to make the shadow softer, you will need to enlarge the light source (and possibly dim it proportionally to the enlargement). A localized blur around the light source is probably your best bet.